# Use AWS Lambda to create CSV and save to S3 (Python)

Tags: python, csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I've got some Python code that goes to a URL, parses an HTML table, and saves the result to a CSV. Changes to the table happen frequently, and I'd like a trending view of these changes. To accomplish this, I'd like my code to run as a function in Lambda, and save snapshots of the table to S3 every 12 hours.

I've created the Lambda, used CloudWatch to trigger the function based on time, and given it permissions to access the relevant S3 bucket, BUT I can't find any resources on how to *save* the output of the function to said bucket. Any pointers or alternate suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

(Note: I have found a resource on here that describes this process using Node, which isn't out of the question, but I'd prefer to remain in Python if possible.)

Comment: best is probably to use boto: http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/s3_tut.html

Comment: `boto3`, not `boto`, is the way to go: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

```
import boto3


S3obj =boto3.resource('s3').Object(bucket, key)

Filecontents = S3obj.get()['Body'].read()
....
S3obj.put(Body=newfilecontents)
```

Sorry for any typos its hard to answer when using a phone to type